# Modify MySQL result on Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I am building the API to provide the files link for the user.
The Database is storing the fileid and the filename. And all the file is storing in same directory.

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  File   |
+----+---------+
| 01 | abc.jpg |
| 02 | cde.mp3 |
| 03 | efg.doc |
+----+---------+
```

When I using php the build the API

```
 $sql = "SELECT id,file FROM `test’";
 if($stmt=$conn->prepare($sql)) {
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $file);
   $array = array();

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     $array[] = array('id' =>$id, 'path'=>'http:// abc.com/file/' . $file);
   }

   $json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 } else {
 }

 print_r($json);
```

I can bind the result and modify them. then the result will like this

```
[{"id": "01", "path": "http:// abc.com/file/abc.jpg"}, 
{"id": "02", "path": "http:// abc.com/file/cde.mp3"}, 
{"id": "03", "path": "http:// abc.com/file/efg.doc"}]
```

Now , I have to build it again by Node.js , I found A tutorial [here](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/restful-api-node-and-express-4/)

The code of outputing on node.js is like

```
 res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "Success", "Users" : rows}
```

Any way to modify the result on nodejs ? It seems no bind result function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rows` object can be treated as you would a *Javascript* array. You'll simply need to create a transformed output:

```
var users = []; // This will hold the transformed output

for (var user in rows) {
  // Modify the file property
  user.file = 'some path' + user.file;
  // Add the transformed user to the 'users' array
  users.push(user);
}

res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "Success", "Users" : users});
```